# Problem with Zend_Db_Abstract in Model

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I've found out that when I extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` in my model I get

## An Error Ocurred

### Aplication error

When I run this code

```
<?php

class Admin_Model_News
{
    protected $_name = 'news';
    protected $_primary = 'new_id';

    public function addNews($data) {
        $this->insert($data);
    }
}
```

It works properly, but when I run

```
<?php

class Admin_Model_News extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'news';
    protected $_primary = 'new_id';

    public function addNews($data) {
        $this->insert($data);
    }
}
```

It messes up
What could be wrong? You can check some of my files [here](http://gist.github.com/561053)

Comment: How many more times will you ask the same basic question? Did you look at any of the answers I and others have givin you?

Comment: I asked and you didn't answered correctly, I'm just trying to find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the insert in a try catch block:

```
try{
    $this->insert($data);
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->__toString();
}
```

This will give you a more detailed error message then application error. AND PLEASE comment here if it doesnt work dont post a new question AGAIN.

Comment: It doesn't even call the addNews() method. If I wipe out the whole class, it still gives the error

Comment: I wraped it in the `$db = new Admin_Model_News();` and it said `No adapter found for Admin_Model_News` how do I solve this?

Comment: DO you initialise Zend_Db in your bootstrap with config from  application.ini?

Comment: I'm using `resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL` I thought it did automatically

Comment: No it doesnt. I guess you fixed it. If not just search here you will find plenty of example of bootstraping your db resource.